# Can't find docker secrets' folder ('/run/secrets')

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, docker-secrets

I played with https://labs.play-with-docker.com/.

I chose the template of `3 Managers and 2 Workers`:
[image]

I went to `manager1` and created a secret:

```
echo "mydatabasepassword" | docker secret create db_pass -
```

I checked and the secret is exist:
[image]

I wanted to check the secrets folder but it doesn't exist:
[image]

I also tried like this:
[image]
Any idea where can it be ?

Following Bret Fisher answer, here is an example:
[image]

*I could get the name of the container only from the manager leader.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Secrets are stored on the manager host in the encrypted raft db, so you can't view them from host. To see them in a container you need to assign them on docker service create, so:

```
docker service create --secret=db_pass --name example nginx
```

Then from the node that was assigned the container you can see the text file in the container (container name will be different):

```
docker exec example.1.m1c4bvubej64xc1csclnq7y3r cat /run/secrets/db_pass
```

Answer (score 1):

As per the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/secrets/#how-docker-manages-secrets):

> When you grant a newly-created or running service access to a secret,
>   the decrypted secret is mounted into the container in an in-memory
>   filesystem. The location of the mount point within the container
>   defaults to /run/secrets/ in Linux containers
>
> The secrets are stored in the encrypted Raft logs for the swarm.

(To learn more about the encrypted Raft logs, see [here](https://medium.com/lucjuggery/raft-logs-on-swarm-mode-1351eff1e690).)